# Can't resolve promise from sequelize.query

Tags: sequelize.js, es6-promise

This will no doubt be embarrassing, but can anyone tell me why the promise from the simple raw query below doesn't resolve? It's sequelize 4.37.10.

Thanks

```
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const options = {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'transitdispatch',
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres'
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(options);
const p = new Sequelize.Promise(function(resolve) {
    return sequelize
        .query('SELECT * FROM "Schedule";', {type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then((schedules) => {
            return resolve(schedules);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});

p.then((schedules) => {
    console.log(`there were ${schedules.length} schedules`);
});
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Is your query running successfully?

Comment: Hi, yes it runs successfully, and the console.log() statement executes with the correct number of rows returned from the database. But the promise chain is still pending somewhere. The script hangs at the command line and I have to manually stop it. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not Promise. Node process will exit automatically when there is nothing to do. In this case, if you close the sequelize connection, it should exit

```
p.then((schedules) => {
    console.log(`there were ${schedules.length} schedules`);
    sequelize.close();
});
```

You can also use `process.exit()` if you are sure you want to exit even if there is something else pending. You can use

```
process._getActiveHandles();
process._getActiveRequests();
```

to figure out what is holding your node process to exit.

Comment: I debugged into the sequelize code and found the problem - which is pretty much what you are saying, my friend. For some reason sequelize is calling this.connectionManager.getConnection(options) twice but only calling this.connectionManager.releaseConnection(connection) once. So I manually called sequelize.close().

Comment: I'm just getting up to speed on v4, and I don't recall ever needing to do this in sequelize v3; sequelize always closed the connection for me. The docs for close() even say "Normally this is done on process exit, so you only need to call this method if you are creating multiple instances, and want to garbage collect some of them." So I'm uncertain whether the docs or the code is wrong. But I have a solution. thanks!